# About FormArray in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on sample Angular 2 application , and I am using ReactiveForms  module.

Below is the code which creates FormGroup , FormControls and FormArray.

```
//-- create formgroup , Reactive form
this.fg = this.fb.group({
                       "ticketID": [""],
                       "title":["title" ,   Validators.compose([Validators.required , Validators.maxLength(50)])],
                       "description":["description" , Validators.compose([Validators.required , Validators.maxLength(50)])],
                       "projectID":["" , Validators.required],
                       "severityID":["" , Validators.required],
                       "statusID":["" , Validators.required],                           
                       "comments": this.fb.array([
                        this.fb.group({
                                        "commentID": [""], 
                                            "commentDate":[""],
                                            "commentText":["comment text"]      
                                      })
                        ])
                     });
```

Below is my template code

```
<form [formGroup]="fg" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" formControlName="title"><br>
   <input type="text" formControlName="description"><br>      

   <select formControlName="statusID">
<option [value]="status.statusID" *ngFor="let status of statuses | async">
    {{status.statusText}}
</option>
   </select><br>
   <textarea formControlName="????"></textarea><br> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit1"><input type="button" value="Reset" (click)="onReset()">
</form>
```

My question is how do I refer the "commentText" formControl in below html field

```
<textarea formControlName="????"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea [formControl]="fg.get('comments').at(2)"></textarea><br>


//-- create formgroup , Reactive form
this.fg = this.fb.group({
                       "ticketID": [""],
                       "title":["title" ,   Validators.compose([Validators.required , Validators.maxLength(50)])],
                       "description":["description" , Validators.compose([Validators.required , Validators.maxLength(50)])],
                       "projectID":["" , Validators.required],
                       "severityID":["" , Validators.required],
                       "statusID":["" , Validators.required],                           
                       "comments": this.fb.array([
                           new FormControl(),
                           new FormControl(),                    
                           new FormControl("comment text")
                        ])
                     });
```

Comment: I've got "comment text" in textarea, http://plnkr.co/edit/TfGtjhCo0vU6MIReqNLY?p=preview

Comment: or if you leave your "comments" code try to bind textarea as <textarea [formControl]="fg.get('comments').at(0).get('commentText')"></textarea>

Comment: My logic is - first you have formGroup so use "get('comments')" method, then you have formarray and first element of it is formGroup so use "at(0)", and then we get formGroup - we call get('commentText')